# Two users (admin + non-admin) what is the right usage of su/sudo?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sudo

I have two users on a macos. `U1` is a non-admin user and `U2` is a admin user.

I cannot add `U1` to the sudoers. Is there a way to use `U2` to act as if it was `U1` issuing `sudo <command>`?

My thinking:

1. `U1> su U2`
2. `U2> sudo -u U1 <command>`

Is this the correct way to achieve the same result as if `U1` could issue `sudo <command>`?

I tried to set an environment variable as `U1` before line 1. and print it out in 2. with `sudo -u U1 echo $VAR` and it worked, i get the correct value back. But I am still unsure that's the correct process to install complex packages etc. from `U2` on behalf of `U1`.

Any corrections/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, just omit the `-u U11`:

1. `U1> su U2`
2. `U2> sudo <command>`

Note that you'll have to authenticate at each step; in both steps, you use the U2 user's password.

Explanation: `su` and `sudo` are both ways of effectively switching user identities (or, more accurately, running commands as a different user identity). Generally, when you use `sudo`, it's to run commands *as the root user*. You can use `sudo -u someotheruser` to run commands as someone/something other than root, but by default `sudo` runs commands as root, and that's presumably what you're trying to do.

(People sometimes talk about running things "as `sudo`", but that's nonsense; what they're actually talking about is using `sudo` as a tool to run things *as root*.)

What the steps in your question would do is to 1) use `su` to switch from U1 to U2, then 2) use `sudo -u U1` to switch *back* to U1, leaving you pretty much right back where you started.